# Failed web service unit tests behind a proxy in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, unit-testing, proxy, junit

I have a problem executing unit tests in Eclipse behind a proxy, as the classes used by the unit tests call some web services, which are behind a proxy. In Tomcat I can of course specify a proxy to be used, but when I run unit tests directly from Eclipse, the proxy configuration of Eclipse seems to be ignored. How can I configure my unit tests or Eclipse to use a proxy in this case?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I found the solution: apparently one can configure the proxy in run/debug settings in Eclipse. To do this:

1. right click on the unit test class
2. debug as - debug configurations
3. go to tab "Arguments"
4. add proxy configuration to "VM arguments":

   - `-Dhttp.proxyHost=proxy.host.com`
   - `-Dhttp.proxyPort=8080`
   - `-Dhttp.nonProxyHosts=[list of hosts separated with pipe character]`

If you are behind a password protected proxy, you have to add:

- `-Dhttp.proxyUser=someUserName`
- `-Dhttp.proxyPassword=somePassword`

Comment: Maybe obvious to veteran Java developers, but you need to put a dash (-) in front of each argument when you add it to the VM arguments section in Eclipse (or at least I did).  Ex: -Dhttp.proxyHost=abcd.com -Dhttp.proxyPort=8888.

Comment: Edited answer accordingly, thanks for pointing that out (the dashes were in my original answer, but were apparently edited out when improving the formatting).

Comment: You should also note that the proxy configuration for HTTPS uses a slightly different property eg. -Dhttps.proxyHost=proxy.host.com. I was wondering why this wasn't working for me at first and it was because my code uses HTTPS.