# How to call web service via proxy on eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, web-services, proxy

Eclipse connects network via proxy server. The proxy settings the HTTP, HTTPS, SOCKS host, port & credentials are seems OK.

I can create web service client using "http://www.webservicex.net/stockquote.asmx?WSDL". However when I try to call the service I get te exception:
 `java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect`

Any suggestions?

Comment: The Solution is here :
[Failed web service unit tests behind a proxy in Eclipse][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1497957/failed-web-service-unit-tests-behind-a-proxy-in-eclipse?lq=1

Comment: Is the web server which the web service is deployed running?